# split character based on condition to do a word

Tags: r

I have some character that i want to concatenate depending on a condition.

input :

```
char_df = data.frame(character = c("a","h","a","o","h","o"),
                         prediction = c(1,0,0,1,0,0)
                    ) 
char_df$character <- as.character(char_df$character)
char_df
  character prediction
1         a          1
2         h          0
3         a          0
4         o          1
5         h          0
6         o          0
```

Basically each time it see 1 it should concatenate the characters ( but not for the first row) 
So on this case it will do 
a,
ah,
aha (done)
o , h , o ( done)

I have written a code that does it 
output:

```
words <- list()
word <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(char_df)){
  word <- paste0(word,char_df[i,1])
  if(char_df[i,2]==1 & i > 1 ){
  words <- c(words, substring(word,1,nchar(word)-1)) 
  word <- NULL
  word = paste0(word,char_df[i,1])
  }
}
words <- c(words, substring(word,1,nchar(word)))
```

output expected:

```
do.call(rbind,words)
     [,1] 
[1,] "aha"
[2,] "oho"
```

My question is more about efficiency , I have sure there a better way to have my expected output without looping row by row , if you have an idea on how to do

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: do.call(rbind,words) . what is coming out from this at the bottom

Comment: There are millions of ways to do this, in base R or using `data.table` and `dplyr`. For instance: `aggregate(character ~ cumsum(prediction),data=char_df,FUN=paste,collapse="")[,2]`.

Comment: Or with `data.table` `setDT(char_df)[, paste(character, collapse="") , cumsum(prediction)]` or `with(char_df, tapply(character, cumsum(prediction), FUN = paste, collapse=""))` or `library(dplyr); char_df %>% group_by(cumsum(prediction)) %>% summarise(val = paste(character, collapse=""))`

Comment: Alright thanks guys i will see what is the logic of both of your solutions